# Returning the function that called this function

Tags: python, function, return

Ok, so, I am writing a Python(v2.7) code with a function to display an error message. But there are a couple of other functions which rely on this original error-checking function.

Now, when this error-checking function is called, and if there is an error, I wish to display an error, and call the function that called this error function.

Example, if `error()` is called upon by `function1()` and there is no error, `error()` function will do nothing important. Now, `function1()` calls `function2()`. When `function2()` calls the `error()` function, it detects an error, displays an error message, and calls `function2()` again. This is what I want to do, but I dont know how to return the calling function back again.

Comment: This is a broken idea. Why do you think you need this? There's almost certainly a better (less hacky) way.

Comment: This seems *way* too complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Implicitly recalling the calling function is bound to lead to infinite loops, bugs (unless you make absolutely sure all methods calling error are idempotent, even when prematurely aborted), confusion, and utterly unpythonic anyways. What you're looking for is just regular error handling:

```
def f2():
   try:
       1/0 # complicated code, potentially raising an error
   except ZeroDivisionError: # Or BaseException, if you gotta catch them all
       error()
       # clean up, restore a consistent state
   # go on, no matter whether the error occurred or did not
```

If simply retrying helps, you just write it out:

```
 def sometimes_fails():
     1 / random.randint(0,1)

 def f():
    while True:
        try:
            sometimes_fails()
         except ZeroDivisionError:
            continue # try again
         break # abort
```

Using a generic name like `error` for highly unusual, extremely complicated (idempotent) and therefore error-prone behavior is not a good idea.

<sub>This answer is brought to you by [`On Error Resume Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as(v=vs.80).aspx).</sub>

Comment: I would like to make it more specific. So, when a user is asked to enter some data in an appropriate format, and when it is correct, the function continues, but when another function has the same requirement, and if it is not fulfilled, only that function should be recalled with the error()'s error message.

Answer (score 3):

*phinag* correctly mentioned that this a bad idea.  But if you still need it, `inspect` module can help:

```
import inspect

def foo():
    print globals().get(inspect.stack()[1][3]

def baz():
    foo()

baz() # prints <function baz at 0x0...>
```

Comment: Alright. I still have some confusion, but I might choose another way to do it. Thanks anyways.